# Get selected option's text in an HTML select using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, selectedtext

I have a html below. How can I get the text of second  tag i.e. *"Frame Size"*.

```
<div class="productOptionViewSelect">
    <div class="selector fixedWidth" id="uniform-08876c63593c0928fefc45101870c7b0"><span style="-webkit-user-select: none;">Frame Size</span><select class="validation" id="08876c63593c0928fefc45101870c7b0" name="attribute[1318]">
        <option value="">-- Please Select --</option>

                    <option value="2527">Frame Size</option>
                    <option value="206">10x15 (4x6 in)</option>
            </select></div>
</div>


<div class="productOptionViewSelect">
        <div class="selector fixedWidth" id="uniform-08876c63593c0928fefc45101870c7b0"><span style="-webkit-user-select: none;">Frame Size</span><select class="validation" id="08876c63593c0928fefc45101870c7b0" name="attribute[1318]">
            <option value="">-- Please Select --</option>

                        <option value="252">Photo Size</option>
                        <option value="206">10x20 (4x6 in)</option>
                </select></div>
    </div>
```

I can get the value of the select by

```
$('.productOptionViewSelect').find('select').val();
```

But this will not fulfill my requirement. Any option can be selected so i can't use above jQuery.

> Edit

If i have same block twice with different sets of option than how can i get the second option of each block? In this case i want **Frame Size** and **Photo Size** but in every event call it only returns **Frame Size**
.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use selector like this:

```
$('.productOptionViewSelect option:eq(1)')
```

because in this result set only one of those options will have index `1` - the index of the second option in second `.productOptionViewSelect` div will get the index equal to the index of the last option in first div plus `2`.

Therefore yo should iterate over those 2 sets of options and use `.text()`:

```
$('.productOptionViewSelect').each(function(){
    console.log($(this).find('option:eq(1)').text());
});
```

Output:

```
Frame Size
Photo Size
```

Comment: I always want second option.so option:selected couldn't be used.

Comment: OK, I see, I edited back, but I don't know what selector to choose for your another set - just change class name or whatever to match it.

Comment: I edited my question to make you more clear. In may case i can't change my class or structure.above is the code.can i use each() or something like that to get both data

Comment: OK, but you should change your question title - it is "selected" now, I would go for "Get text of options with the same index, but in two separate divs with the same class name" or sth like that.

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
$('.productOptionViewSelect').find('select option:selected').text()
```

It will give you the text inside of the `<option>`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the text of selected option, you need to get the jquery object of selected option and then use `.text()` or `.html()` to get inner content in it:

```
$('.productOptionViewSelect option:selected').text();
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$('.productOptionViewSelect select').find('option:selected').text();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("select.validation option:eq(1)").text();
```